# Importing multiple large data to AWS RDS Postgres making it slow

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, import, amazon-rds

In our current Application we take day wise backup to our s3 bucket. These backups are per day and per table in a CSV format.

Our requirement is to import data from s3 for some date range, lets say we needed to see data from 1st Jan, 2015 to 31st July 2015, we download data from s3 to out ec2 instance and import to the newly created postgres DB.

But as time goes the import becomes horribly slow. Following are steps I have doing during import:

1. Create RDS postgres-9.6 instance with m3-XLarge and 600GB space and General SSD Storage type.
2. Switched off replica and multi AZ instances.
3. Import schema with no foreign key and no index.
4. Set tables to UNLOGGED and switched off autovacuum.
5. Use COPY command for import.

   `psql -h <HOST_NAME> -d <database_name> -U <user_name> -c "\COPY TABLE_NAME FROM '<exact_path_of_the_file>' CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER"`

When the import starts it easily consumes file of 2GB within 2 mins. But after importing data for a month the import becomes very slow. For importing file of same size the time increases to 30 mins (I'm comparing file size for the same table for 2 different date).

I have tried splitting file into smaller chunks and do the importing, but didn't see any improvement in the import timing.

What I Have observed from RDS monitoring is that the swap space has increased from 0 to 50... Don't know if thats normal. Any input for improving import will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

**[PS: All steps are in shell command]**

Comment: whats your ops?.. is it provisionned?

Comment: @VaoTsun I am using GeneralSSD... Which was the bottle neck.... After changing it to Provisioning IOPS  and increasing the number of iops, the import became faster... Thank you

Comment: @VaoTsun After increasing the number of iops to 8k, the import became faster, which earlier it became slow after importing data of 50GB.... That did worked out, but after importing data of around 200GB it has again became slower... Read IOPS is at 3k and Write IOPS is at 5k... Do you see any other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#USER_PIOPS

> The ratio of the requested IOPS rate to the amount of storage
>   allocated is important, and depends on your database engine. For
>   example, for Oracle, the ratio should be between 1:1 and 50:1. You can
>   start by provisioning an Oracle DB instance with 1,000 IOPS and 200
>   GiB storage (a ratio of 5:1). You can then scale up to 2,000 IOPS with
>   200 GiB of storage (a ratio of 10:1). You can scale up to 30,000 IOPS
>   with 6 TiB (6144 GiB) of storage (a ratio of 5:1), and you can scale
>   up further if necessary.

Postgres has same ratio (1:50), also iops are not bytes ps, its operations, so when you give 8K piops, its not 8KB or MB per second. I would suggest you increasing piops to 40K, importing the data and then decreasing it back.